# Woocommerce Rest API is not working on live server

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I have uploaded woocommerce API on live server but is not working given blank response but it's successfully work on localhost.

Following is my code for get order by id

```
<?php
    include('../wp-load.php');
    require_once( 'woo-lib/autoload.php' );

    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

    $woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://tesmy.com', 
    'ck_xxxxx', 
    'cs_xxxx',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v1',
    ]
);



if(isset($_REQUEST['order_id']) && empty($_REQUEST['order_id'])){
    $result = array('status'=>false,'message'=>'Order id is required.');     
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo  json_encode($result);
    die();
}


$orderId=$_REQUEST['order_id'];

$orderDetails=$woocommerce->get('orders/'.$orderId);

if(isset($orderDetails) && !empty($orderDetails)){
    $result = array('status'=>true,'message'=>'Order details','data'=>$orderDetails);
}else{
    $result = array('status'=>false,'message'=>'Something went wrong');
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo  json_encode($result);
die();
```

This same thing is worked on my local server but not working on live server.

Please help me what should id do for this ?

Comment: do you have a ssl cert. on your live server? if not, try adding.

Comment: Yes,ssl cert is already available.